# Vorticity and circulation of fluid

Tags: fluid-dynamics

Does a fluid with velocity $q =\left (z-\frac{2x}{r},2y-3z-\frac{2y}{r},x-3y-\frac{2z}{r}\right)$ posses vorticity? What is the circulation in the circle $x^2+y^2 = 9$, $z =0$ ?

where $r^2=(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)$

PS: This question has been asked already but I wanted to know the concept behind it. 
I am getting Vortex vector as zero vector. Does vorticity means vortex vector is zero ?

And what is the difference in circulation and vorticity ? Shouldn't the circulation be also zero here as vortex vector is zero ?

Comment: Does this help? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulation_%28fluid_dynamics%29?wprov=sfla1

Comment: I got the vorticity part. But not the circulation one. According to the page vorticity is circulation per unit area. So circulation should also be zero ?

Comment: Circulation is the integral of vorticity across a surface, so if the vorticity is zero, the circular is zero.

Comment: See the section "Relation to vorticity" in the link